# pgf scatter plot without coloring

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to make a scatter plot from a `.csv` without any coloring. I'm using `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{mytable.csv}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = x,
    ylabel = y,
]

\addplot[scatter, only marks] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{\mytable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And in `mytable.csv`:

```
x,y
0,3
1,4
2,1
3,2
4,9
5,0
```

When I compile this everything looks nice, except the dots are colored. Is there a way to make all the markers black? Sorry if this is a dumb question

**Edit:**

This is what I ended doing (based off of the answers I got -- thanks!):

```
\addplot[only marks, mark options = {black}]
```

For some reason, if I left `scatter` in the `\addplot` options it wouldn't let me change the color of the marks. Right now everything is working great with no errors

Comment: welcome to tex.se! how you imagine, that we can test your code? it is not fun to write missing part that your code became compilable ...  please extend it to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Zarko My bad, just edited it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 1: After checking warning messages.**

In this case removing `scatter` from `\addplot` options also works. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis lines = left,
xlabel = x,
ylabel = y,
]
\addplot[only marks] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    2,3
     4,5
     3, 8
 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above produces:

[image: black scatter mark]

Comment: This looks great, but now I get a bunch of warnings saying: `Package pgfplots Warning: scatter/classes: can't find class for '-2'!? Please make sure you have specified 'scatter src=explicit symbolic'. Ignoring class '-2' (this message will not come again). on input line 75.`?

Comment: you need `mark options={black}` or whichever properties. classes are for scatter class plots

Comment: @percusse would I put that in the options to `\addplot`?

Comment: I missed the warnings in TeX-studio. I am not sure how to do it with `scatter` option enabled and without using style for classes. However, if you remove scatter from your original list of options (Edited MWE) then it works. In this case, you can also add ` mark options={blue}` (or any property)as percusse mentioned.